# sass mixin not found errors from package.json build scripts

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have a site that I inherited that has all of it's styles defined in various .scss files however the site was missing a package.json file so I needed to re-create it.

After getting all the dependencies worked out and attempting to run the build script, it continuously throws an error:

```
Error: Undefined mixin.
   ╷
15 │   @include body-copy;
```

The mixin is defined in a file titled base.scss and is located in a directory titled base ( base/_base.scss ) and is being imported like so:

```
@import 'base/base';
```

I was also using wildcard syntax for globbing as well but have commented it out thinking there might have been an issue with the globbing procedure

```
@import 'base/**/*.scss';
```

my package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "cmt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/Automattic/_s.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/Automattic/_s)",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass --importer node_modules/node-sass-glob-importer --output-style compressed assets/css/style.scss assets/css/main.css",
    "build": "sass assets/css/style.scss assets/css/main.css --style compressed"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssnano": "^6.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "node-sass-glob-importer": "^5.3.3",
    "postcss-cli": "^11.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.70.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  }
}
```

Originally I was trying to use node-sass with the glob procedure to get all files imported with wildcard syntax

I've tried creating the two build scripts above but both hit the same errors.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or missing here?

I have tried switching node versions between 12 -20 and reinstalling node_modules after every switch

Switching from using node-sass to just sass without globbing

Manually moving mixins to the main scss file ( not ideal as there are many mixins )

I've checked the import paths, haven't observed issues with the Sass version, haven't obversed issues with typos, cleared sass-cache

I also created a super basic version of the project with just an index.html file, mixin.scss file, main.scss file and the same package.json file.

The build script defined works with the basic sass but the sass script defined generates the same "Error: no mixin named body-copy" error.

Any ideas about what's wrong here? It seems to be in the sass script but I cannot figure out what the issue is...